# EditText in kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, calculator

I'm learning kotlin in Android Studio.
I have an error to build the calculator.
I have an error in EditText (edtNumber).
please guide me

......Please see the pictures......

===============================

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:hint="@string/app_name"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:textSize="20pt"
        tools:text="0" />
```

==================================

[edtNumber](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBaBv.jpg)

[error edtText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S88C7.jpg)

[rror edtText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW8Oh.jpg)

Comment: You need to add `viewBinding` in your `build.gradle` then you can use binding 
`binding.edtNumber.`

Comment: thanks , how to do this?

Comment: You can read about it [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)